# One code to turn all forms into AJAX forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So I use the following code to manipulate my 'login' form so that it submits it, to the url of action="" and the data responded goes into id specified by target="". The submit method is specified by method=""

I like this. It's neat. But I was wondering if there was a way of having a script that meant that all forms were submitted through Jquery, without having to re-write this code for every form every time. That's just messy.

Much appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#login").submit(function(){
         var thistarget = this.target;
         $(thistarget).html('Submitting...');   
         jQuery.ajax({
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             url: this.action,
             type: this.method,
             error: function() {
                 $(thistarget).html("Form failed to submit");
             },
             success: function(results) {
                 $(thistarget).html(results);
             }
         })
         return false;
         }
    );
});

</script>
```

Comment: Sure, just replace `"#login"` with `"form"`. It will then affect all forms that currently exist on the page (but not future forms).

Comment: Yup. Perfect. Feel stupid for asking such a simple question now. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just replace `"#login"` with `"form"`. It will then affect all forms that currently exist on the page (but not future forms).

```
$("#login").submit(function(){...
```

For future forms AND current forms, you would need event delegation.

```
$(document).on("submit","form",function(){...
```

Comment: Can $(document).on() be used in conjunction with $(document).ready() ?

Comment: @TomMac It can't be chained after .ready() (i think? i may be wrong there), however it can be used inside of it, outside of it, before it, or after it.

Comment: Hmm when I've tried using it outside it/inside it/before/after it it seems to mess up the document.ready function.

Comment: Are you matching up all the proper `{` and `(` with `)` and `}`?

Comment: Pretty sure the issue it's throwing an error when there isn't a form on the page, but if there is then it's fine.

Comment: That really shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think I must have been making a silly mistake elsewhere. Either way - your help was much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd use the $.post method of Jquery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
But answering your question and as Kevin B said: change *#login* by *form*